# jquery close tab from right click menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I am doing close current tab, close another tab, and close all tabs functions from right-click tab menu option. I am facing difficulty in the close current tab. The code can perform close current tab from the right-click menu. But, when I click left or right mouse click on any tab before clicking on tab I want to close. `All the clicked tabs closed together`. Why it happened and how to solve it?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown-menu").hide(100);
  $(document).bind("mousedown", function(e) {
    // If the clicked element is not the menu
    if (!$(e.target).parents(".dropdown-menu").length > 0) {
      // Hide it
      $(".dropdown-menu").hide(100);
    }
  });
  $('#tabs').on("mouseup", "a.tab", function(event) //right click on tab
    {
      switch (event.which) {
        //left-1,center-2,right-3
        case 3:
          //alert('Right Mouse button pressed.');
          $(".dropdown-menu").finish().toggle(100).
          css({
            top: event.pageY + "px",
            left: event.pageX + "px"
          });
          break;
      };
      var tabid = $(this).attr("id");
      //console.log(tabid);
      $('#dropdown-menu a').click(function() {
        var menuchoosed = $(this).attr("id");
        switch (menuchoosed) {
          case 'TabCloseCurrent':
            // remove tab and related content
            $("#" + tabid).remove();
            var contentname = tabid + "_content";
            $("#" + contentname).remove();
            /*
            $(this).parent().remove();
            */
            // if there is no active tab and if there are still tabs left, show the first one
            if ($("#tabs li.active").length == 0 && $("#tabs li").length > 0) {
              // find the first tab    
              var firsttab = $("#tabs li:first-child");
              firsttab.addClass("active");
              // get its link name and show related content
              var firsttabid = $(firsttab).find("a.tab").attr("id");
              $("#" + firsttabid + "_content").show();
            }
            break;
          case 'TabCloseOther':
            break;
          case 'TabCloseAll':
            $("#tabs li").remove();
            break;
        }
      })
      //tabid=''; 
    });
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html oncontextmenu="return false">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Tabs</h3>
    <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a class="tab" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a id="Menu1" class="tab" href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a id="Menu2" class="tab" href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a id="Menu3" class="tab" href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <p><strong>Note:</strong> This example shows how to create a basic navigation tab. It is not toggleable/dynamic yet (you can't click on the links to display different content)- see the last example in the Bootstrap Tabs and Pills Tutorial to find out
      how this can be done.</p>
  </div>
  <ul id="dropdown-menu" class='dropdown-menu'>
    <li data-action="first"><a id="TabCloseCurrent" class="TabCloseCurrent" href="#">Close Tab</a></li>
    <li data-action="second"><a id="TabCloseOther" class="TabCloseOther" href="#">Close Other Tabs</a></li>
    <li data-action="third"><a id="TabCloseAll" class="TabCloseAll" href="#">Close All Tabs</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you click on the tab, you create click event for each of those tabs. Also, if you need `tabid` you can refer the following snippet to store it using [`$().data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) and retrieve it in the click event:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown-menu").hide(100);

  $(document).bind("mousedown", function(e) {
    // If the clicked element is not the menu
    if (!$(e.target).parents(".dropdown-menu").length > 0) {
      // Hide it
      $(".dropdown-menu").hide(100);
    }
  });


  $('#tabs').on("mouseup", "a.tab", function(event) {
    //right click on tab
    switch (event.which) {
      //left-1,center-2,right-3
      case 3:
        //alert('Right Mouse button pressed.');
        $(".dropdown-menu").finish().toggle(100).
        css({
          top: event.pageY + "px",
          left: event.pageX + "px"
        });
        break;
    };

    //var tabid = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#dropdown-menu').data('tabid', $(this).attr("id"));
    //console.log(tabid);
    //tabid=''; 
  });

  $('#dropdown-menu a').click(function() {
    var menuchoosed = $(this).attr("id");
    var tabid = $('#dropdown-menu').data('tabid');
    switch (menuchoosed) {
      case 'TabCloseCurrent':
        // remove tab and related content
        $("#" + tabid).remove();
        var contentname = tabid + "_content";
        $("#" + contentname).remove();
        /*
        $(this).parent().remove();
        */
        // if there is no active tab and if there are still tabs left, show the first one
        if ($("#tabs li.active").length == 0 && $("#tabs li").length > 0) {
          // find the first tab    
          var firsttab = $("#tabs li:first-child");
          firsttab.addClass("active");
          // get its link name and show related content
          var firsttabid = $(firsttab).find("a.tab").attr("id");
          $("#" + firsttabid + "_content").show();
        }
        break;

      case 'TabCloseOther':
        break;

      case 'TabCloseAll':
        $("#tabs li").remove();
        break;
    }
    $(".dropdown-menu").hide(100);
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html oncontextmenu="return false">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h3>Tabs</h3>
    <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a class="tab" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a id="Menu1" class="tab" href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a id="Menu2" class="tab" href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a id="Menu3" class="tab" href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <p><strong>Note:</strong> This example shows how to create a basic navigation tab. It is not toggleable/dynamic yet (you can't click on the links to display different content)- see the last example in the Bootstrap Tabs and Pills Tutorial to find out
      how this can be done.</p>
  </div>


  <ul id="dropdown-menu" class='dropdown-menu'>
    <li data-action="first"><a id="TabCloseCurrent" class="TabCloseCurrent" href="#">Close Tab</a></li>
    <li data-action="second"><a id="TabCloseOther" class="TabCloseOther" href="#">Close Other Tabs</a></li>
    <li data-action="third"><a id="TabCloseAll" class="TabCloseAll" href="#">Close All Tabs</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```